# Can not looping JSON result in the view of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I added the data to the list , and return it as JSON in my controller :

```
List<ProductListingModels> prom = new List<ProductListingModels>();
ProductListingModels product = new ProductListingModels();

foreach (var item in ien_item)
{
   if ((item.Brand.IsAuthorized == true) && ((HelperClass.ICEContact.PathBrandImages + 
   item.Brand.Image) != null))
   {
     product.BrandImage = HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist(item.Brand.Image);
   }
   else
   {
     product.BrandImage = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }
}

prom.Add(product);
return Json(new
{
   ja = prom.ToList()

}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is in my view :

```
$.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
  $.each(data, function (index, proValByDep) {
     alert(proValByDep.BrandImage);
  });
```

});

I traced it in firebug ready, the JSON works well. 
The problem :

```
proValByDep.BrandImage is undefined.
```

Any solution please. Thanks so much.

Comment: `{"ja":[{"BrandImage":"http://pd:8080/Product/Brand/28.PNG"}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the proble is that you are using the `data` variable in the `each()` method, that you pass to the request, instead of the `product` parameter that holds the returned data..

```
$.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {

  //   changed data to product below and also added .ja as you want to access its value
  $.each(product.ja, function (index, proValByDep) {
     alert(proValByDep.BrandImage);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to loop on `data.ja` as it is array, rather than on `data` directly.

```
$.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
  $.each(data.ja, function (index, proValByDep) {
     alert(proValByDep.BrandImage);
  });
});
```

Or you may change server-side to directly return array, rather than wrapping it in property named `ja`

```
return Json(prom, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I used the first solution, it doesn't alert any thing, and  I got an error `Error: a is undefined, Source File: http://localhost/jquery.min.js`

Comment: For the second solution : It is alert undefined.

Comment: This works fine -     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var data = { "ja": [{ "BrandImage": "http://pd:8080/Product/Brand/28.PNG"}] };

            $.each(data.ja, function (index, proValByDep) {
                alert(proValByDep.BrandImage);
            });
        });
    </script>